# How to read the real and complex numbers in a unified way in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, complex-numbers, fortran95

Suppose I have a data file (fort.100) including the data like,

```
2.34,          4.5
(23.1,0.3),    4.5
(3.1,0.3),    (3.2,1.0)
2.4,          (32.2,12.0)
```

how to read these mixed real and complex values to the complex variables?
In other words, the following simple way does not work in gfortran.

```
program readmixnum
implicit none
integer::i
complex::cdat(4,2)
do i=1, 4
read(100,*) cdat(i,1:2)
write(*,*) cdat(i,1:2)
end do
end program
```

Actually, we can assign a real value to the complex variable but why reading the real values cannot. I am wondering there must be a very simple solution for this.

Comment: What was your attempt? Did you get any errors? In what type of code you need to incorporate this? What are your data structures? Did you try writing  your own parsing , or did you use Fortran formatting, or only tried the list-formatted read?

Comment: Figure out what your specs are, then code them. e.g,: Discard whitespace and commas to find next entry. If an entry starts with a paren, read a complex else read a real. And so on.

Comment: Do you realize that you dimensioned cdat with 3 rows but tried to read 4? If I fix that, the code works correctly.

Comment: It does not work correctly in gfortran after the change, though. But the the error message, with other information, should be a part of the question. "does not work" does not say anything useful and should not appear in good questions.

Comment: That's a very poorly designed file to read, if at all possible make it much simpler to parse when reading, so simple you can use *list-directed* input without trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this as simple solution for your issue:

```
program readmixnum
implicit none
integer::i,st
character*256::line
real::rdat(4,2)
complex::cdat(4,2)
do i=1, 4
  read(100,'(A)',iostat=st) line
  read(line,*,iostat=st) rdat(i,:)
  cdat(i,:) = rdat(i,:)
  if (st /= 0) then
    read(line,*,iostat=st) rdat(i,1), cdat(i,2)
    cdat(i,1) = rdat(i,1)
    if (st /= 0) then
      read(line,*,iostat=st) cdat(i,1), rdat(i,2)
      cdat(i,2) = rdat(i,2)
      if (st /= 0) then
        read(line,*,iostat=st) cdat(i,:)
      endif
    endif
  endif
  write(*,*) cdat(i,1:2)
end do
end program
```

It needs one real matrix `rdat` with the same rank as your complex one `cdat`. One line of the input file `fort.100` is saved in the `line` variable. This prevents the `backspace` statement during the checks of the number format.

The checks of number format are done with `iostat` parameter. If this value equals 0, then the reading is successful and the number format correct. The challange is to try out all possible combinations.

The output is:

```
 (  2.33999991    ,  0.00000000    ) (  4.50000000    ,  0.00000000    )
 (  23.1000004    , 0.300000012    ) (  4.50000000    ,  0.00000000    )
 (  3.09999990    , 0.300000012    ) (  3.20000005    ,  1.00000000    )
 (  2.40000010    ,  0.00000000    ) (  32.2000008    ,  12.0000000    )
```

for compilation with `gfortran` version 6.3.0 on a Linux machine.

Hope it helps.